# How to delete event in Google Calendar using API v3 .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I have this method:

```
public static void DeleteEvent(CalendarService service, Event eventToDelete, string calendarId = "primary")
{
    service.Events.Delete(calendarId, eventToDelete.Id);
}
```

but it's failing to delete any events from the calendar.

What's am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any Error or Exception? Is other operations are working there?

Comment: @un-lucky I'm not getting any exceptions or errors. The program keeps running. It just fails to delete any entries.

Comment: I have added an answer below, Please take a look, and let me know what happening now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is Add an `.Execute()` at the End of the line to execute the delete command, then it will be like the following:

```
 service.Events.Delete(calendarId, eventToDelete.Id).Execute();
```

You can refer [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/869770/Handling-events-in-google-calendar-using-google) as well for more informations